# How to display negative numbers which are not currency?

Tags: numbers

I'm writing an application that will be showing negative numbers of units (as in shares of stock).

When showing negative numbers in currency, [it's typical to display the it in parentheses](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/1875/41541), e.g. `($100)`.

We also need to display numbers of units of stock, but since these are not a currency, should they be displayed in parentheses, or with a minus sign? e.g. `(100)` or `-100`? While they're not currency, they are closely related to currency.

What would be the correct way to display these negative numbers of units? Is there a standard or is it up to the company to decide?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, it's *only* currency that is conventionally displayed within parentheses in US English. All other quantities, however financially significant, are displayed with a leading minus.

There may be some locales where a different distinction is drawn, but for the most part I would expect either one or two formatting styles, based on whether the amount is directly valueable in money or rather represents some quantity or percentage of things.